# Dynamic sizing of SSRS Report

Tags: reporting-services, dynamic-resizing

I have a report with 12 Tablixes on it.  The user can pick and choose which one of these Tables and their associated data shows when the Report is generated.  However, when chosing a subset of the 12 tables, the report shows blank space where I hide the non-selected tables.  Is there any way to make the report resize/fit the size of the selected tables...truncating the white space where the invisible tables are?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off welcome to SO.

I personally have not been able to find a way to truncate that white space. The best solution I've found is to just design my reports around it.

Also, Sub-Reports, or a Tablix of Tablixes may come in handy for this solution.

So, yeah, those are the routes I would explore:

- Design report around white space
- Sub-Reports
- Tablix of Tablixes

Comment: Hello Meiscooldude...thanks a lot for the response.  I like the idea of a Tablix of Tablixes.  That should help.  I tried SubReports but found the same issue.  They still took up space even when invisible.

Cheers

Comment: I tried the Tablix of Tablixes but had an issue. The inserted Tablixes each need their own DataSet....however, the External Tablix requires a DataSet and the internal Tablixes inherited this DataSet. I didn't see a way around that. So, I sized the individual Tablixes to be super small and did not put them in a mutual Tablix.  When they are invisible there is very little white space...and when they are visible they expand to fit the data...

Comment: SSRS lacks a ton of features, and it seems like to get something to display the way we want, we have to hack our way around it... this gets quite annoying... I'm not familiar with how SSRS handles Queries that return multiple data sets, perhaps you might look down that road? (use one query for all)

Answer (score 0):

put your tables on rectangles, and optionally hide the rectangles based on your requirements.  In the report settings, set consume white space to true.  That should do it for you.